# How do i use this code to Display the UUID in a Label?

Tags: xcode, label

Can someone who is willing to explain the steps to a beginer help me? I am trying to lean but things seem to be above my head :( LOL

Here is the code that i have, i need the Label to display the UUID right as the application is opened. (I am using a storyboard)

Code:

```
+ (NSString *)createUUID
{
    NSString *uuidString = nil;
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    if (uuid) {
    uuidString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));
    CFRelease(uuid);
}
return uuidString;
```

}

Comment: Have you created the label in your view controller in your storyboard?

Comment: I have the Label that I would like to use in my ViewController yes, that's all that you mean by 'create' right now right?

Comment: So, have you tried using the createUUID method and display it in a label? What are the issues you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Try NSLogging uuid string if its correct then add yourLabel.text = uuidString. I am guessing you have connected your labels correctly. if yes, then this should work.